# Calling Functions in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
public void CreateMySqlCommand() 
 {
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryID";
    myCommand.CommandTimeout = 15;
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 }
```

Can I use Sql Server functions in myCommand.CommandText and why?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "SQL Server Functions" do you mean stored procedures?

Comment: "why"?! Do you mean "how"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you mean, [SQL Server user defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Then, **yes**; you can use it normally like:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT fn_Yourfunctionname(@parameternames)";
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parameternames", ...
```

The reason it works is because this is the way that functions are called in SQL Server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
    public T ExecuteScalarFunction<T>(string functionName, List<SqlParameter> parameters, SqlDbType returnSqlType) where T : new()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(CTX.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(functionName, conn)) { 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", returnSqlType).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return (T)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
```