# How to call a function in a command?

Tags: c#, function

I want to use the function "MyPlaces". What should I use instead of `commandType.StoredProcedure`

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyPlaces", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //This part gives me an error 
        string email = Session["oldemailuser"].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        string s = "<br />";
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
          string name = s + " " + rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("name"))
                        + "   located in ";
          string location = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("location")) 
                            + "&nbsp;&nbsp";


         Label lbl_name = new Label();
         lbl_name.Text = email;
         form1.Controls.Add(lbl_name);

         Label lbl_location = new Label();
         lbl_location.Text = email;
         form1.Controls.Add(lbl_location);

     }
 }
```

Comment: Whats the problem, where is the error?

Comment: Some explanation would be good?  e.g. Based on SqlClient, do we assume you mean a SqlServer UDF? Is the UDF a Scalar function or Table Function?

Comment: this is my function 


ALTER function MyPlaces
(@email varchar(50))
returns table
AS
RETURN
select p.name ,p.location
from likes l inner join place p on l.place_id = p.id
where l.user_email = @email

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048398/calling-functions-in-sqlcommand

Answer (score 0):

Hope your sql function name is "Myplaces".If So,Then Modify your code with this :

```
string email = Session["oldemailuser"].ToString();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MyPlaces(@email)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));
conn.Open();
```